# How can I insert number (concatenate) at the beginning of every line using linux

Tags: linux

I have file that contains numbers each number in one line. I want to add '00' to exisitng values in the file at the beginning of every line. Ex: if I have 22, 33, 44 each number in line, I want them to be: 0022, 0033, 0044. i.e, concatenate.

How can I achieve this please ? If not possible, then, how can I remove 00 form existing values in the file ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a replacement and save it in the same file, try:

```
sed -i 's/^/00/' filename
```

To leave the file intact, remove `-i` from the command.

To remove zeroes, use

```
sed -i 's/^00//' filename
```

Comment: This is to add 00 ?? I also figured out I need to remove 00. Can you please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, and not touching numbers starting with 00:

```
sed -i '/^00/!{s/^\([0-9]*\)/00\1/}' input_file
```